# How do I stop Windows Electron App from launching a new window on notification click?

Tags: windows, push-notification, electron

I'm using the HTML5 Notification API in the render layer of an electron application. On Windows, when a notification is clicked, the click event in the render layer is triggered AND a new app window is opened.

The `onclick` handler in the render layer is called as expected, but the call to `preventDefault` doesn't stop a new window from opening.

```
let notification = new Notification(title, options);
notification.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // notification click handling here works as expected 
  // in the existing window.

  notification.close();
};
```